# MANTA (Structural Variant Detection Tool) on Centos 8

Tags: bioinformatics, centos8

Good evening,
I have Centos 8 as operative system (OS) installed on my working station. I would like to install MANTA, but Centos 8 is not listed among the OSs on which this tool has been tested (https://github.com/Illumina/manta/blob/master/docs/userGuide/installation.md#prerequisites-to-build-from-source).
I wanted to know if somebody ever used it on Centos 8, or it is a waste of time trying to make it work.
Thank you all!

Comment: Manta is available through [Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/). There is very rarely a need for anyone to build from source these days.

Answer (score 2):

## Install Through Bioconda

This can be installed via [Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/). I did a quick test on a CentOS 8 Docker image ([centos:centos8](https://hub.docker.com/layers/centos/library/centos/centos8/images/sha256-dbbacecc49b088458781c16f3775f2a2ec7521079034a7ba499c8b0bb7f86875?context=explore)) and seems to work fine (though I didn't test on an actual BAM), so I think you should be good. Below are the steps.

### Install Steps

1. **Install Conda.** There are lots of options here, but I'd recommend [some Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download). I specifically installed the [Miniforge3-Linux-x86_64](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-Linux-x86_64.sh) version. I'd note that one should say `yes` to running `conda init`, then run `source ~/.bashrc` when the installer is done.
2. **Install Manta in an environment.** Since Manta involves Python scripts, and requires Python 2, you'll need a new environment. Here's the command:

   ```bash
   conda create -n manta -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults manta
   ```

   This installs Manta v1.6.0 for me.
3. **Activate environment.** The environment needs to activated to use it.

   ```bash
   conda activate manta
   ```
4. **Run a Manta script.** For example, here's the output for running the config command:

   ```bash
   configManta.py
   Usage: configManta.py [options]

   Version: 1.6.0

   This script configures the Manta SV analysis pipeline.
   You must specify a BAM or CRAM file for at least one sample.

   Configuration will produce a workflow run script which
   can execute the workflow on a single node or through
   sge and resume any interrupted execution.

   Options:
     --version             show program's version number and exit
     -h, --help            show this help message and exit
     --config=FILE         provide a configuration file to override defaults in
                           global config file (/opt/miniforge3/envs/manta/share/m
                           anta-1.6.0-1/bin/configManta.py.ini)
     --allHelp             show all extended/hidden options

     Workflow options:
       --bam=FILE, --normalBam=FILE
                           Normal sample BAM or CRAM file. May be specified more
                           than once, multiple inputs will be treated as each BAM
                           file representing a different sample. [optional] (no
                           default)
       --tumorBam=FILE, --tumourBam=FILE
                           Tumor sample BAM or CRAM file. Only up to one tumor
                           bam file accepted. [optional] (no default)
       --exome             Set options for WES input: turn off depth filters
       --rna               Set options for RNA-Seq input. Must specify exactly
                           one bam input file
       --unstrandedRNA     Set if RNA-Seq input is unstranded: Allows splice-
                           junctions on either strand
       --referenceFasta=FILE
                           samtools-indexed reference fasta file [required]
       --runDir=DIR        Name of directory to be created where all workflow
                           scripts and output will be written. Each analysis
                           requires a separate directory. (default:
                           MantaWorkflow)
       --callRegions=FILE  Optionally provide a bgzip-compressed/tabix-indexed
                           BED file containing the set of regions to call. No VCF
                           output will be provided outside of these regions. The
                           full genome will still be used to estimate statistics
                           from the input (such as expected fragment size
                           distribution). Only one BED file may be specified.
                           (default: call the entire genome)

     Extended options (hidden):
   ```